# Python: GLM multidimensional input

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, python

I'm trying to fit a GLM model to some data. My response variable, y, is a vector of length 24, my inputs x are a 24 * 24 data frame. My code looks like this:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

pm1 = sm.GLM(x, y, family=sm.families.Poisson(sm.families.links.log))
pfit = pm1.fit()
```

I get the following error at the pfit = pm1.fit() line:

> ...if s[i] > cutoff:
>   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
>    Use a.any() or a.all()

I tried putting in some test values to see if it just doesn't like using data frames, like so:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4],[2,2,2,3]]
y = [2,4,6,12]
```

But now it tells me:

> ValueError: endog and exog matrices are different sizes

Does anyone have any idea what's happening. Let me know if I haven't provided enough detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, your matrices are not dimensnionally aligned.  Try this instead:

```
x = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2], [4, 3]]  # 4 by 2
y = [2, 4, 6, 12]  # 4 by 1
sm.GLM(x, y, family=sm.families.Poisson(sm.families.links.log))
<statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM at 0x11220d990>
```

For using a data frame, statsmodels supports a formula api

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
d = pd.DataFrame({'x_1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'x_2': [2, 2, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 6, 12]})
smf.glm(formula='y ~ x_1 + x_2', data=d, family=sm.families.Poisson(sm.families.links.log))
<statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM at 0x10805e790>
```